# Summernote Toggle Bottons Issue

Tags: summernote

I am using summernote 0.8.0. When I am pressing toggle buttons for actions(e.g Bold,Underline,Italic), the buttons remain in the unpressed appearance until I type something.Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same version css file?

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.0/summernote.css
```

Comment: Yes I am using the same

Comment: try latest version

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem. Please try latest version of Summernote i.e Summernote 0.8.9 This bug persists in older versions. 
Please see the link :   https://jsfiddle.net/7jnf1bv4/ 
cdn link:

```
Js:
<script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.9/summernote.js"></script>

CSS:    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.0/summernote.css" />
```

Comment: The reason of using that version was I wanted to have the functionality of user mentions which was not available in earlier versions.Hope this new version should suppport that functionality as well

Comment: Sorry! i don't know much about it.

Comment: Implemented in my code.The earlier issue was resolved.Now the buttons are working fine.However I am facing issue in selecting the option from the dropdown. Type @ you will find the list but you wont be able to select any option.https://jsfiddle.net/7jnf1bv4/2/

Comment: it is working fine at my end. i am able to select item by enter Key!

Comment: Yes it is working by enter key.However in the last version which I was using I was able to select the item from the mouse as well.